# SQL multiple parameters in pg_prepare

Tags: php, sql, parameters

```
$result = pg_prepare($conn, "city_update", "UPDATE lab5.city SET population = $1 WHERE lab5.city.name = '$2'");
$result = pg_execute($conn, "city_update", array("$updatedPop", "$name"));
```

This is saying that my prepared statement has only 1 parameter.

I'm not sure where I went wrong. The SQL query works in PSQL.

Answer (score 0):

remove `'` around `$2`, in prepared statement you should not hace to use `'` for variables

```
$result = pg_prepare($conn, "city_update", "UPDATE lab5.city SET population = $1 WHERE lab5.city.name = $2");
```